# Could some one find the error in this code?

Tags: c++

I've written this program, when i run it and input 20.14, this is the output:

Enter the amount: 20.14
Change Due:

20 dollars
0 quarters
1 dimes
0 nickels
3 pennies

It should have been 4 pennies. But it shows 3.
Here's another output:

Enter the amount: 79.58
Change Due:

79 dollars
2 quarters
0 dimes
1 nickels
3 pennies

But for some reason, here is calculated it right.

Can anybody help me find the error? 
Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
//Description: This program takes in a dollar amount from the user and
//and calculates and displays how to make the change using the smallest
//number of bills and coins possible.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declaring the variables.
    //dollarAmount is the amount that will be input by the user, which
    //will be split into dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies.

    float dollarAmount;
    int dollars = 0, quarters = 0, dimes = 0, nickels = 0, pennies = 0;

    //Displaying message to user to input value for dollarAmount.

    cout << "Enter the amount: ";

    //Taking in the value for dollarAmount.

    cin >> dollarAmount;

    //Splitting the dollarAmount into dollars, quarters, dimes,
    //nickels and pennies.

    pennies = dollarAmount * 100.0;
    dollars = pennies / 100;
    pennies = pennies % 100;
    quarters = pennies / 25;
    pennies = pennies % 25;
    dimes = pennies / 10;
    pennies = pennies % 10;
    nickels = pennies / 5;
    pennies = pennies % 5;




    //Displaying a message to the user with desired output

    cout << "Change Due:\n\n";
    cout << dollars << " dollars\n";
    cout << quarters << " quarters\n";
    cout << dimes << " dimes\n";
    cout << nickels << " nickels\n";
    cout << pennies << " pennies\n";


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just print out the values after each and every line of code and see where it goes wrong.  Debug your own code, don't dump it on others.

Comment: i tried so many times, i just can't understand why it gives wrong output.

Comment: `20.14`, like most finite decimal fractions, cannot be exactly represented in a `float`. The actual representation is some number that's a tiny bit larger or a tiny bit smaller. It appears that you are unlucky and it's smaller - say, `20.13999999`. You multiply that by 100 and truncate, ending up with `2013` pennies. Try `pennies = dollarAmount * 100.0 + 0.5;` - this rounds, rather than truncating.

Comment: It worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `std::fmod` included in `<cmath>` in order to compute floating-point remainder of the floating-point divisions .